# Launcher Icons (Legacy only) showing white background icon android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-studio-3.3

In android studio 3.3 when I am trying to import image for launcher icon using legacy only option its showing white background icon even after importing the image its showing same and not changing the icon with imported one.

See the screenshot:
[image]

What's the problem with android studio 3.3? Any solution?

Comment: Do you want to have a launcher icon with transparent background?

Comment: No, I just want to have my launcher icon as what i am uploading as png.

Comment: Try to use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html by setting `Asset Size` to 48, `Asset Padding` to 0 and `Color` to transparent. Then move the generated images into mipmap directories.

Comment: That's manual approach. Why android studio image asset not working for generating those images?

Comment: Did you select your image png by clicking on `Path` because I don't see it in the image above.

Comment: select launcher icon(legacy only) and then select asset type image. Path will be shown

Comment: Just change the **shape to none** & you'll good to go with your original icon as launcher.

Comment: What about reporting this as a bug? AS 3.3 is a beta version, so it might be an error coming with the IDE and you should [report this bug](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs#how_to_report_a_bug); I can't think at any other solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Android Studio 3.3, pending the time before it gets fixed. You can be using this awesome open source tool by someone in the community.

GOTO

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

SELECT Launcher icon generator

[image: Launcher icon generator]

SELECT Image and choose the image from the explorer dialogue

[image: Image and choose the image from the explorer dialogue]

Your selected image will be shown in the right-hand side as below

[image: Your selected image will be shown in the right-hand side as below]

The finally, you can download the icon generated in mipmap folder

[image: The finally, you can download the icon generated in mipmap folder]

You can also set varieties of options from the left-hand side, options like the background color, color, padding, shape, effect and the generated file name.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I created the icons with this but still the icons just have a shadow of image no image is showing

Answer (score 0):

1 > Select Launcher Icon (legacy only)

2 > Select Asset Type : Image

3 > copy paste your image path or select png image by click on the three-dot button right of the textbox

4 > Now open **Shape**(second last option from bottom) drop-down menu and select option **None**

5 > Now you can see your png image without the background as you selected

Comment: No luck. Same issue in android studio 3.3

Comment: Do you select none in Shape Option?

Comment: Yes, I did. Did you try with android studio 3.3?

Comment: I have Ubuntu and have last updated android studio 3.2.1 which is latest updated for Ubuntu and its all working fine

Answer (score 0):

From asset studio select

**Asset Type** : Clipart

And select any file from the samples and confirm the image is properly appearing on the right side window.

If **YES**

Again select **Asset Type** : Image

[image]

From there you can navigate to an image path directly instead of copying and pasting image path.

*Note: Please confirm that the image you choose fulfills the specifications for a launcher icon.*

[image]

Usually, I import  Google play icon 512*512 (Both my Google play and Launcher icons are same) to Asset studio where other icons sizes will be automatically scaled down by Android Studio Itself

Comment: For Clipart and Text its working properly but for Image its not working.

Comment: Can you share me your image file?

Answer (score 0):

Successfully replicated the issue; it appears to be a bug in Android Studio 3.3.
I have filed a bug report.